# How to limit the number of objects given from nested serialization

Tags: django-rest-framework

`Store` has a foreign key to `SimilarStore`. Normally, there is about a hundred of similar stores in `similarstore_set`. Is there a way to limit the number of similar stores in `similarstore_set` when I make API with `Django REST Framework`?

**serializer.py**

```
class SimilarStoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SimilarStore
        fields = ('domain', )


class StoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    similarstore_set = SimilarStoreSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'
```

**UPDATE**

The following codes throws `'Store' object has no attribute 'similarstores_set'`, it actually has `similarstore_set`, why is it throwing the error?

```
class StoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    image_set = ImageSerializer(many=True)
    promotion_set = PromotionSerializer(many=True)

    similar_stores = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_similar_stores(self, obj):
        # get 10 similar stores for this store
        stores = obj.similarstores_set.all()[:10]  <-- This line throws the error
        return SimilarStoreSerializer(stores, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to perform a custom lookup and limit the number of records:

```
class StoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    similar_stores = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_similar_stores(self, obj):
        stores = obj.similarstore_set.all()[:10] # get 10 similar stores for this store
        return SimilarStoreSerializer(stores, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can you check out the updated post? I tried your codes, but it has some issue.

Comment: @Jay try it with `similarstore_set` (not `similarstores_set`).

Comment: Stunning! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` for `similarstore_set` and define a method that would query the `SimilarStore` data and set `similarstore_set`.  You could pass the number of elements you want in `similarstore_set` by passing context to your serializer. see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context